# How can I solve Mixamo animation going to origin point?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, graph-editor, actions, mixamo

Mixamo animation; my character sad idle to turn 180° then I add another action but that action going to origin point how can solve it?

This my animation of Mixamo action how can I solve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frkc2.png)

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to select the first spine bone and rotate it 180° in the Graph Editor, but please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/